# How can i remove the div when time expires?

Tags: javascript

So i have a countdown watch, that goes down from whatever time u set it in days & hours to 0 . For example,i set 1 day , whenever the day expires there remains the div with the styling,how can i make it that when the day expires and there are only hours left to remove that div? The watch looks like 
https://i.gyazo.com/83866f9d620d6c87e39ce43b64c92956.png
The code is

```
var countdown_text = '<span class="theme-watch days">' + days +
  '<spam style="font-size:17.5px">' + day_string + '</span>' +
  '</span>' +
  '<span class="theme-watch hours">' + dig(hours, 2) + '</span>' +
  '<span class="theme-watch minutes">' + dig(minutes, 2) + '</span>' +
  '<span class="theme-watch seconds">' + dig(seconds, 2) + '</span>' +
  "<span id='countdown_miliseconds' class='theme-watch'>" + dig(miliseconds, 3) + "</span>";
```

Comment: `<spam` Spelling matters in programming.

Comment: @CertainPerformance You could have edited the quertion. Everyone with basic knowledge of HTML would now that it is a `span`

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal If it's a mistake made by the OP, it's not something that should be fixed by someone else via an edit to OP's question (and typo problems should not be answered anyway) - thus, my comment.

Comment: @CertainPerformance You are talking nonsense, and your comments are unpleasant and unhelpful.  There is not reason why a question with a typo cannot be answered, if the meaning is clear; and there's no reason why an obvious typo cannot be corrected through an edit

Comment: @Peter Once you have the ability to vote to close questions, take careful note of this option: `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.` Typos are **off-topic**. That said, the root of the question here isn't a typo, thankfully.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think you are be applying the law rather than the spirit of StackOverflow.  If you can help someone with a typo, why not?  And as you point out, in this case they typo wasn't the issue, so why the snide comments?  Someone with your "experience" on SO should be setting a better example.

Answer (score 0):

you could use an `if` clause or a ternary operator:

```
var countdown_text = (days > 0) ? '<span class="theme-watch days">'+days+' <span style="font-size:17.5px">'+day_string+'</span></span>' : '';
countdown_text += '<span class="theme-watch hours">'+dig(hours,2)+'</span>'+'<span class="theme-watch minutes">'+dig(minutes,2)+'</span><span class="theme-watch seconds">' + dig(seconds,2)+'</span>'+"<span id='countdown_miliseconds' class='theme-watch'>"+dig(miliseconds,3)+"</span>"; }
```

a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is a shorthand to write "`if` `condition` then value is x `else` it's y

it's the equivalent of

```
if(days > 0){
   var countdown_text = '<span class="theme-watch days">'+days+' <span style="font-size:17.5px">'+day_string+'</span></span>';
}else{
   var countdown_text = '';
}
```

Comment: I tried using the folowing
    if(days <= 0) {
      $('.days').hide();
    }
however it doesn't work

Comment: then I do not have enough information about your code. WHERE did you put that `if`? what function executes every second to update your clock?